# checking textbox as null or not java android

Tags: java, android

I am creating a login page with username and password as mandatory fields. Error message "Username & Password is empty" should be thrown if these mandatory fields are empty. But nothing happens as per the below code.

Following is My Code

```
public class Login_testingActivity extends Activity{
EditText edit1,edit2;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_username);
    EditText edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);

    if (edit1.getText().length() != 0 && edit2.getText().length() != 0) {
        fun();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Login_testingActivity.this, "You need to enter a high AND low.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
     public boolean fun(){

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login_2.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });

        return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors in the LogCat??

Comment: Was my flow of program right? please reply

Comment: no see my answer where to put `if` conditon

Comment: add .show(); at the last of toast.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!!.I ran that program successfully

Answer (score 7):

```
 Toast.makeText(Login_testingActivity.this, "You need to enter a high AND low.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

First this  line`if (edit1.getText().trim().length() != 0 && edit2.getText().trim().length() != 0) {`

add in `onClick(View view)`  and check there `if(){startActivty(...);}else{Toast here..}`

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
if (edit1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") && edit2.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
         Toast.makeText(Login_testingActivity.this, "You need to enter a high AND low.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
  else 
    {
         fun();

    }
```

Comment: this doesn't work, because you do not call show() when calling Toast.makeText()

Comment: @Hasmukh: Its still wrong. You are doing exactly opposite!..If its not blank you are showing a Toast to the user...!

Comment: ya that i know but i missed it sry.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this work for you.

```
if (!edit1.getText().equals("") && !edit2.getText().equals("")) {
    fun();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(Login_testingActivity.this, "You need to enter a high AND low.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, because you do not call show() when calling Toast.makeText()

Answer (score -1):

Use This Lines As

```
if (edit1.getText().toString().length() > 0 && edit2.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        fun();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(Login_testingActivity.this, "You need to enter a high AND low.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't work, because you do not call show() when calling Toast.makeText()

Comment: Do You check That Question Correctly "checking textbox as null or not java android" without knowing what is question dont give somebody nagative comments

Comment: @bindal: Your else statement anyways will not work. Have you even tried this?